# Trouble getting the correct pay response from the PPMessage.php Core File when using PPMessage::init() function?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm working in a custom PAYPAL adaptive payments gateway and I'm having problems getting the right pay response (new PayResponse) in php. I have tracked the error and I found it in the core file PPMessage.php. My payment gateway can create the following paykey with Paypal adaptive payments:

```
$resp = array (
  'responseEnvelope.timestamp' => '2016-02-05T06:57:57.098-08:00',
  'responseEnvelope.ack' => 'Success',
  'responseEnvelope.correlationId' => 'e24f3c602852a',
  'responseEnvelope.build' => '17820627',
  'payKey' => 'AP-62K58588W7248331V',
  'paymentExecStatus' => 'CREATED',
);
```

when I want to translate it to a pay response I do the following:

```
    $ret = new PayResponse;

    $ret->init($resp);
```

PayResponse extends PPMessage which defines the method init. However, the core file PPMessage gives me the following answer:

```
ret=PayResponse::__set_state(
        array( 
            'responseEnvelope' => NULL, 
            'payKey' => 'AP-62K58588W7248331V', 
            'paymentExecStatus' => 'CREATED', 
            'payErrorList' => NULL, 
            'paymentInfoList' => NULL, 
            'sender' => NULL, 
            'defaultFundingPlan' => NULL, 
            'warningDataList' => NULL, 
            'error' => NULL, 
        ))
```

The problem is with the responseEnvelop key, since it should be an array and I'm getting NULL. I don't know how to modify the PPMessage::init method in order to fix the problem. Can anyone help me? The correct pay response should be as follows:

```
PayResponse::__set_state(array(
   'responseEnvelope' =>  ResponseEnvelope::__set_state(array(
          'timestamp' => '2016-02-05T06:57:57.098-08:00',
          'ack' => 'Success',
     'correlationId' => 'e24f3c602852a',
     'build' => '17820627',
  )),
   'payKey' => 'AP-62K58588W7248331V',
   'paymentExecStatus' => 'CREATED',
   'payErrorList' => NULL,
   'defaultFundingPlan' => NULL,
   'error' => NULL,
))
```

Note that in the correct response, the responseEnvelope is an object.

Here is a link to the [PPMessage](https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-php/blob/namespace-5.3/lib/PayPal/Core/PPMessage.php) file form GitHub. Any help from someone who knows the paypal core files would be appreciated. Could anyone check that this error is general or if the problem is unique to my setup?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking more into my setup, I found out that the problem is on my PayPal installation. I'm failing to load the ResponseEnvelope class. There is an error, and the class is not loaded. So I'm closing out this question. Thank you for reading this.